# How to rename a top column to struct column in Dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How do i rename following:
Schema :

```
root
  |-- specialTypeCol_temp: string (nullable = true)
  |-- meta: struct (nullable = false)
      |-- validations: array (nullable = true)
To
root
  |-- meta: struct (nullable = false)
      |-- specialTypeCol_temp: string (nullable = true)
      |-- validations: array (nullable = true)
```

The Schema does exists in Meta Struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename with `select`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.select(struct(
  col("meta.validations").alias("validations"),
  col("specialTypeCol")
).alias("meta"))
```

Same in Python:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, struct

df.select(struct(
    col("meta.validations").alias("validations"),
    col("specialTypeCol")
).alias("meta"))
```

Comment: Would this still be the approach, if we have 40 columns? Could be there any other way to avoid selecting all columns?